# How to fix Alamofire 5 Error: "Cannot specialize non-generic type 'DataResponseSerializer'"?

Tags: ios, swift, generics, alamofire, swift5

I am updating a Network Foundation to Swift (and Alamofire) Version 5.

One method that should provide "Generic Response Object Serialization" is throwing the error

> Cannot specialize non-generic type 'DataResponseSerializer'

I think in Alamofire 5 they made the Type `DataResponseSerializer` non-generic. Any ideas how to achieve the same behavior in the newest version? Unfortunately I am not very familiar neither with Alamofire nor `Generics`.

```
public extension Alamofire.DataRequest {

  @discardableResult
  func responseDecodableObject<T: Decodable>(completionHandler: @escaping (DataResponse<T>) -> Void) -> Self {

    //error is thrown here
    let responseSerializer = DataResponseSerializer<T> { request, response, data, error in

        guard error == nil else { return .failure(error!) }

        let result = DataRequest.jsonResponseSerializer(options: .allowFragments).serializeResponse(request, response, data, error)

        switch result {
        case .success(let value):
            do {
               let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: value, options: .prettyPrinted)
               return .success(try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data))
            } catch {
                return .failure(ErrorSerializer.JSONDecoderFailed(json: "\(value)", errorText: error.localizedDescription))
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            return.failure(error)
        }
    }

    return response(responseSerializer: responseSerializer, completionHandler: completionHandler)
  }
}
```

I found many Tutorials that show ways to achieve this, but all of them share the generic DataResponseSerializer. For example: [Medium](https://medium.com/@mhacnagbani/alamofire-generic-response-object-serialization-using-codable-13db342347b2)

Comment: Don't think you need the `<T> ` when declaring the block, it works fine for me without it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're correct, `DataResponseSerializer` is no longer generic in Alamofire 5.

More importantly, Alamofire now has support for `Decodable` built in with `responseDecodable` and `DecodableResponseSerializer`, so you don't need to write it yourself.

Comment: please help me (-: I try to change app that not I written and have this func and can't find any good replacment, public static func objectSerializer<T: Parseable>(by parser: T) -> DataResponseSerializer<ParseResult<T.ReturnedType>>